# Running gunicorn from Dockerfile not working, but works with manual start

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

This is my project structure -

```
/app
  /config
  /controllers
  /lib
  /schemas
  /static
  /templates
  /tests
  __init__.py
Dockerfile
wsgi.py
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /.requirements.txt

COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

ENV FLASK_APP=iterative.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=development


CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 wsgi:app
```

This is what my `wsgi.py` looks like

```
from app import app

print("IS WSGI BEING RUN")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("IS THIS RUNNING")
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, threaded=True)
```

This is what my `__init.py` looks like

```
from flask import Flask
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
print("IS INIT.PY RUNNING")
```

This is what I do

1. I run `docker build -t  .
2. I then run `docker run 80:8000 <app_name>`

This is the output I get

```
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8547] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8547] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (8547)
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8547] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8550] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8550
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8551] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8551
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8552] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8552
[2019-04-03 09:52:09 +0530] [8553] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8553
```

Note that there are **no** print statements coming out.

I then ssh into the docker container by doing

`docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`

I then run (I run it at an arbitrary port just to prove that it works)

`gunicorn -b 9000 -w 4 wsgi:app`

Now this is the output I get

```
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [30] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [30] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.35.40:8000 (30)
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [30] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [33] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [35] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 35
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [36] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2019-04-03 06:25:44 +0000] [38] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 38
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
FLASK ENVIRONMENT: development
IS INIT.PY RUNNING
IS WSGI BEING RUN
IS WSGI BEING RUN
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
FLASK ENVIRONMENT: development
IS INIT.PY RUNNING
IS WSGI BEING RUN
IS WSGI BEING RUN
FLASK ENVIRONMENT: development
IS INIT.PY RUNNING
IS WSGI BEING RUN
IS WSGI BEING RUN
FLASK ENVIRONMENT: development
IS INIT.PY RUNNING
IS WSGI BEING RUN
IS WSGI BEING RUN
```

I check the docker logs to make sure that the output from the container isn't just being written to a log. It is not.

Why is the behaviour different between the two cases?

Answer (score 0):

OK this was really frustrating, and I hope this will help someone else out.

Every tutorial out there does not emphasize the operating system in which Docker runs. Docker does not run the same across all Operating Systems.

In fact, Mac OS, you can only hit your container through localhost.

```
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds
```